# How to get rid of delays on double_click_input() actions?

Tags: python, python-3.6, pywinauto

Is there a way I can get rid of delays on double_click_input() actions?

What I'm trying to do is double click the edit box and then type keys here. Maybe both of these actions have some delay, so the whole process performing looks very slow.

Code:

```
myApp = Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re='myTitle_re')    
myApp.window(auto_id='myAutoId').window(title='myTitle').double_click_input()
myApp.descendants(title='myTitle', control_type='Edit')[1].type_keys('myKeys')
```

And an additional question: I tried to use double_click() here, but it always throws an exception:

> AttributeError: WindowSpecification class has no 'double_click'
>   method.

Then I tried `myApp.window(auto_id='myAutoId').window(title='myTitle').wrapper_object().double_click()`

And got:

> AttributeError: 'ListItemWrapper' object has no attribute
>   'double_click'

What should I change to get this work?

I'm using pywinauto 0.6.3.

Comment: Timings can be aligned using class `pywinauto.timings.Timings`, so that you can set delay to null. I can point to exact variable name in the evening. `double_click` is not implemented because it's unclear what silent action (UIAutomation Pattern) should be interpreted as double click action. We have method invoke and ButtonWrapper.click = invoke alias. But for non-buttons InvokePattern may have different meaning. That's why we left it as `.invoke()`. For `backend="win32"` we have `double_click` using `WM_DBLCLICK` window message. But `double_click_input` is the same for both backends.

Comment: Sorry for delays with details. It's a hobby project we're making out of office hours.

Comment: It's ok, I'll wait. :)
And thank you for `invoke()`, 

it's even better than `double_click_input()` for my case.

Comment: And also how to get text from the edit control? For example the text I just typed in. Tried `window_text()` and `texts()` but it gives me the title of the control instead.

Comment: Hmm... probably you're trying to get text from parent of the edit box. Try `.children()[0].window_text()` and beyond.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a solution. The text (value) I need to get is contained in `LegacyIAccessible.Value` and `Value.Value` in Inspector.exe. Can I even get those using `window_text()`?

Comment: No, you probably need `.legacy_properties()[u'Value']`. Another way is to use `.iface_value.GetValue()`. What is the value of `.element_info.control_type` for your edit box?

Comment: Thanks, `.legacy_properties()[u'Value']` returns me a needed value. `.iface_value.GetValue()` gives me this: `in __getattr__ raise AttributeError(name) AttributeError: GetValue`. And the value of `.element_info.control_type` of my edit box is `DataItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question, you can set some timings to null using global settings. For `double_click_input`:

```
from pywinauto.timings import Timings
Timings.after_clickinput_wait = 0.0
Timings.after_setcursorpos_wait = 0.0
```

For real user input (`*_input` methods) changing timings may cause modified sequence not to work. But you may experiment for your own risk. Sometimes it's better to use silent methods using window messages like `WM_CLICK` (for "win32" backend) or UIAutomation Patterns like Invoke Pattern (for "uia" backend).

`double_click` is not implemented for "uia" because it's unclear which UIAutomation Pattern should be interpreted as double click action. We have method `.invoke()` and `ButtonWrapper.click = invoke` alias. But for non-buttons InvokePattern may have different meaning. That's why we left it as `.invoke()`.

P.S. Regarding legacy propery text... It can be obtained by `.legacy_properties()[u'Value']` for your case (or other value from returned dict). There are methods `set_window_text/set_edit_text` using ValuePattern so the text can be set silently without any tricks.

Comment: Thanks for your help! About those methods: I tried them, but got the exception `AttributeError: WindowSpecification class has no 'set_windiow_text/set_edit_text' method`. I find myself getting exceptions regarding WindowSpecification class too often, so maybe I miss something in the concept of it.

Comment: It's an unclear message in case when the element not found. We're planning to fix it. See [issue #364](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/364).